# CryptoJS cannot compare with pre-hashed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, sha1

i have a password table which containes SHA1 hashed data. so i want to make a validation input with CryptoJS. it went error.. but when i try to display it, the result matched.. did i code a wrong function?

here's my code

```
function checkCurPass()
{
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1("<?php echo $selected->password ?>");
    var currentPass = document.getElementById('users-profile-currentpassword');
    var hashedPass = CryptoJS.SHA1(currentPass.value);

    var message = document.getElementById('mesas');
    message.innerHTML = hashedPass;

    if (hashedPass == hash) 
    {
        $('#currentPassForm').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#currentPassForm').addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    }
}
```

screenshot with hashed 'default'

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, there are no whitespaces like linebreaks at the end of either string? Sorry, bad comment. You're obviously comparing two strings returned from the same hash function.

Comment: yes.. both data excactly the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hashes are no strings, but objects. If you `console.log(hash)`, you'll see this. In order to get a proper hex string from these hashes, call `hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` and `hashedPass.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` respectively.

When you display your hash in your message element, toString is called implicitly, thats why the displayed strings were equal.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNxjGm

Comment: i tried to convert it to string. but still cant match.. do i have to convert both variables?

Comment: yes, otherwise you would be comparing a string to an object ;)